# Can multiple EffectComposer render in same WebGLRender?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Can multiple EffectComposer render in same WebGLRender?

[codepen demo](http://codepen.io/sanlang/pen/xVmXjQ?editors=0011)

this is my code, it's not work. but renderer.render() is ok, not with effect.
someone can debugging my code?

```
var renderer;
var scene1, scene2;
var camera;
var geometry1, geometry2;
var FilmShader; 
var composer1, composer2;

scene1.add(geometry1);
scene2.add(geometry2);

var renderPass1 = new THREE.RenderPass( scene1, camera );
var renderPass2 = new THREE.RenderPass( scene2, camera );
var filmPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.FilmShader );

composer1 = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);
composer2 = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);

composer1.addPass(renderPass1);
composer1.addPass(filmPass);
composer2.addPass(renderPass2);
composer2.addPass(filmPass);

// It's not work, just render composer2(or composer2 cover composer1)
composer1.render();
composer2.render();

// It's ok, but on effect
renderer.autoClear = false;
renderer.render(scene1, camera);
renderer.render(scene2, camera);
```

Comment: codepen demo is very clear. someone help me ?

Comment: Maybe, but you will have to be very careful and do something like `composer2.renderTarget2 = composer.renderTarget1;` and set `renderPass2.clear = false;`. (Not tested.) I suggest you use only one composer.

Comment: I trid what your said. but it still didn't work, maybe checkout my codepen demo?

Comment: You are going to have to spend hours of work and understand every line of the post-processing code if you want to figure out how to do what you are trying to do. Sorry, I can't do that for you.

Comment: thank you, I will figure out.

Comment: You will learn a lot by doing so. If I knew the answer I would tell you. : - )